# peer-to-peer replication in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3814591/Peer-to-Peer-Replication-in-SQL-Server-2008--Configure-a-two-node-topology.htm

here i can see peer-to-peer replication option but this options are not in my SQL 2008 r2 standard edition server. Is this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN article on the topic: [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx). Fromt he General Considerations section:

> Peer-to-peer replication is available
>   only in **SQL Server 2008 Enterprise**.

Comment: ok, does it have to be clustering or can be configured without shared storage between two servers ?

Comment: @Albert: peer-to-peer replication doesn't have any clustering requirement.

Comment: Cool that is why I'm interested in using this feature and no witness server necessary too.